# Checking whether or not a sequence converges in $C([0,1], \mathbb{R}), \| . \|_{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

I am asked to check whether or not $\{f_n\}_{n≥0}$ and $\{g_n\}_{n≥0}$ in  $C([0,1], \mathbb{R}), \| . \|_{\infty}$ converges. Where $f_n(t) = t^n-t^{n+1}$ ang $g_n(t) = t^n - t^{2n}$

In order to do so, I simply check if  $\| f_n(t) - f(t) \|_{\infty}$ converges and same for $g_n(t)$.

Now, what I don't understand is how we chose $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ I saw the solution nd they simply pick $f(t) = 0$ and $g(t) = 1/n$

Why were theose choices made?

Comment: What is that $1/n$ in the definition of $g$?

Comment: If there is a variable $n$ appearing in the definition of $g(t)$ in your solutions, then the solutions are wrong.

Comment: What is this $f(t)?$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Both $(f_n),(g_n)$ converge pointwise to $0$ on  $[0,1].$ If $(f_n)$ converged uniformly to some $f\in C[0,1],$ then $f\equiv 0,$ since uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence. Same for $g.$ Does this happen?